# nginx gzip not working on browser but curl works

Tags: nginx, gzip

my environment is nginx(1.3.11) + php-fpm

```
curl -I -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" http://www.ihezhu.com/
```

the result is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Server: nginx  
Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2013 07:47:27 GMT  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8  
Connection: keep-alive  
Vary: Accept-Encoding  
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=st7oa6mero58n6lmitlofa4n70; path=/  
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  
Pragma: no-cache  
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

but when i use browser like chrome and the response doesn't contain gzip
[there's a special case : when open http://www.ihezhu.com/list/md_area-c_beijing/f_2000.3000_0_0_0_0_0_0_0.0.0.0.0_0_0-s_time_asc-lt_list-p_1/ , it's response gzip T_T]

what's wrong?

my nginx setting is

```
gzip on;  
gzip_buffers 4 16k;  
gzip_comp_level 3;  
gzip_http_version 1.1;  
gzip_min_length 1k;  
gzip_proxied any;  
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;  
gzip_vary on;  
gzip_disable msie6;
```

thanks

#### my nginx compile options, nginx virson now update to 1.5.2

```
./configure \  
    --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \  
    --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock \  
    --user=nginx \  
    --group=nginx \  
    --with-http_realip_module \  
    --with-http_gzip_static_module \  
    --with-http_stub_status_module \  
    --with-pcre=/var/src/pcre-8.33 \  
    --with-zlib=/var/src/zlib-1.2.8 \  
    --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/client \  
    --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/proxy \  
    --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi \  
    --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/uwsgi \  
    --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/scgi
```

#### update info

the url http://www.ihezhu.com/list and http://www.ihezhu.com/list/md_area-c_shanghai/f_0.0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0.0.0.0.0_0_0-s_time_asc-lt_list-p_1/ has same response content, but only the long one has gzip..

Comment: Same here. My Nginx (nginx/1.8.0) on AWS Ubuntu instance doesn't set `Content-Encoding: gzip` header, if I make a request from a browser. But sets the header all right if I make a `curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"` request. But it seems that Nginx gzip-s responses though. I test with Google's PageSpeed and it doesn't complain about no gzip. Strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your `curl` command works because it sends a `HEAD` request, instead of a `GET` request. Try curl with verbose mode:

  curl -Iv -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" http://www.ihezhu.com/

You will get the same result as in browser with

```
curl -i -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" http://www.ihezhu.com/
```

- "text/html" is always compressed. So it has nothing to do with `gzip_types` directive.
- This happened to me before when my upstream server was using `http 1.0` instead of `http 1.1`. Have you tried the following?

  gzip_http_version 1.0;

[**update**]
Your nginx compile option seems normal. It's hard to understand how url length directly affects nginx on gzip.  Checked the nginx source code. nothing on url is used to determine gzip. Based on the source code, there are 2 possible causes:

1. Your php code returns a non-empty `content-encoding` header with the short url request.
2. Your php code returns a wrong `content-length` header with the short url request, and that length is smaller than 1k.

So the best way is to find the php response header of both urls and start from there.

Comment: change to `gzip_http_version 1.0;` not ok=_=,  [there's a special case : when open http://www.ihezhu.com/list/md_area-c_beijing/f_2000.3000_0_0_0_0_0_0_0.0.0.0.0_0_0-s_time_asc-lt_list-p_1/ , it's response gzip T_T]

Comment: That's strange. Do you have some 3rd party nginx modules installed? If yes, maybe remove those modules and see if it works. Also do you use proxy module to server php-fpm or directly use fastcgi module?

Comment: i add my nginx compile option in question, and i think the reason maybe the url, the url <http://www.ihezhu.com/list> and <http://www.ihezhu.com/list/md_area-c_shanghai/f_0.0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0.0.0.0.0_0_0-s_time_asc-lt_list-p_1/> are the same response content, but the long one has gzip..